# In android studio can't show API data in app.in logcat details below

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

Below some seller id's data cannot be retrieved through API.but API data available.i check it postman app.show seller id's data are using `user_type=1`,but without `user_type=1` seller id's data can n't display in app

```
 01-05 06:33:01.898 8306-8306/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
    01-05 06:33:01.898 8306-8306/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
    01-05 06:33:01.945 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/panaceatek.com.p1021-1/lib/x86
    01-05 06:33:01.948 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is panaceatek.com.p1021, real application class is panaceatek.com.p1021.Application.Application.
    01-05 06:33:02.073 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/panaceatek.com.p1021-1/lib/x86
    01-05 06:33:02.091 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/ACRA: ACRA is enabled for panaceatek.com.p1021, intializing...
    01-05 06:33:02.112 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/ACRA: Looking for error files in /data/user/0/panaceatek.com.p1021/files
    01-05 06:33:02.129 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/ACRA: Looking for error files in /data/user/0/panaceatek.com.p1021/files
    01-05 06:33:02.129 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/ACRA: panaceatek.com.p1021 reports will be sent by email (if accepted by user).

                                                              [ 01-05 06:33:02.649  8306: 8306 D/         ]
                                                              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe770f960, tid 8306
    01-05 06:33:02.797 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
    01-05 06:33:02.797 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
    01-05 06:33:02.798 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    01-05 06:33:02.798 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    01-05 06:33:02.806 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

                                                                [ 01-05 06:33:02.811  8306: 8336 D/         ]
                                                                HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe770fba0, tid 8336
    01-05 06:33:02.844 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    01-05 06:33:02.844 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
    01-05 06:33:02.856 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-05 06:33:02.856 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xd9b0cf20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    01-05 06:33:04.453 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Session class: Session class imag-->null
    01-05 06:33:04.453 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/My cart: hash map-->{customer_id=410}
    01-05 06:33:04.458 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Seller list: Url->{seller_id=410, user_type=1}
    01-05 06:33:04.788 8306-8365/panaceatek.com.p1021 D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
    01-05 06:33:04.798 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    01-05 06:33:04.982 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-05 06:33:04.982 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe9ca40c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    01-05 06:33:05.054 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-05 06:33:05.054 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe9ca4fa0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    01-05 06:33:05.563 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Selller list: Url-->http://dev.joinerytrade.com/webservices/customer/getsellerlist
    01-05 06:33:05.563 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Seller list: Responce-->{"errorcode":0,"msg":"Success","data":[{"store_id":"24","seller_id":"78","name":"Cabinet Market","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_78_logoMP_78_logoCabinetMarket_Logo.png"},{"store_id":"63","seller_id":"228","name":"Kitchens By You","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_228_logokitchensbyyou2.png"},{"store_id":"65","seller_id":"232","name":"Timeless Kitchens","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_232_logoTimeless_Logo.jpg"},{"store_id":"70","seller_id":"266","name":"Flatpack My Kitchen","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_266_logofpmk-small.png"},{"store_id":"72","seller_id":"268","name":"Analyzer Seller","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_268_logoanalyzer.jpg"},{"store_id":"76","seller_id":"275","name":"Starkey & Christoe","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_275_logostarkey_logo3.jpg"},{"store_id":"77","seller_id":"277","name":"HTF","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_277_logoMP_277_logoHTF-Logo.png"},{"store_id":"78","seller_id":"278","name":"Sagar Store Name","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/market_place\/marketplace\/images\/image.jpg"},{"store_id":"80","seller_id":"282","name":"Tori's Cut to Size","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_282_logoTori_final3.jpg"},{"store_id":"84","seller_id":"285","name":"Vish","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/market_place\/marketplace\/images\/image.jpg"},{"store_id":"91","seller_id":"293","name":"Rodds Kitchens and Joinery","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_293_logorodds_kitchens_logo.jpg"},{"store_id":"95","seller_id":"297","name":"SMART FLATPACK & ASSEMBLED","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/market_place\/marketplace\/images\/image.jpg"},{"store_id":"96","seller_id":"303","name":"Jindabyne Joinery","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_303_logoJindy3.jpg"}]}
    01-05 06:33:06.342 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Main activity: url-->http://dev.joinerytrade.com/webservices/checkout/itemsincart
    01-05 06:33:06.342 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Main activity: responce-->{"errorcode":0,"msg":"Success","data":{"totalitems":"0","totalprice":"$0.00"}}
    01-05 06:33:17.983 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Seller cat list: Url-->{seller_id=78}
    01-05 06:33:18.043 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-05 06:33:18.043 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdaf7b220, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    01-05 06:33:18.478 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Selller list: Url-->http://dev.joinerytrade.com/webservices/customer/getsellerproducts
    01-05 06:33:18.478 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Seller list: Responce-->{"errorcode":2,"msg":"There are no products for this store"}
    01-05 06:33:29.166 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Seller list: Url->{seller_id=410, user_type=1}
    01-05 06:33:29.201 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    01-05 06:33:29.201 8306-8336/panaceatek.com.p1021 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdae73f20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    01-05 06:33:29.614 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Selller list: Url-->http://dev.joinerytrade.com/webservices/customer/getsellerlist
    01-05 06:33:29.614 8306-8306/panaceatek.com.p1021 E/Seller list: Responce-->{"errorcode":0,"msg":"Success","data":[{"store_id":"24","seller_id":"78","name":"Cabinet Market","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_78_logoMP_78_logoCabinetMarket_Logo.png"},{"store_id":"63","seller_id":"228","name":"Kitchens By You","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_228_logokitchensbyyou2.png"},{"store_id":"65","seller_id":"232","name":"Timeless Kitchens","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_232_logoTimeless_Logo.jpg"},{"store_id":"70","seller_id":"266","name":"Flatpack My Kitchen","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_266_logofpmk-small.png"},{"store_id":"72","seller_id":"268","name":"Analyzer Seller","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_268_logoanalyzer.jpg"},{"store_id":"76","seller_id":"275","name":"Starkey & Christoe","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_275_logostarkey_logo3.jpg"},{"store_id":"77","seller_id":"277","name":"HTF","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_277_logoMP_277_logoHTF-Logo.png"},{"store_id":"78","seller_id":"278","name":"Sagar Store Name","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/market_place\/marketplace\/images\/image.jpg"},{"store_id":"80","seller_id":"282","name":"Tori's Cut to Size","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_282_logoTori_final3.jpg"},{"store_id":"84","seller_id":"285","name":"Vish","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/market_place\/marketplace\/images\/image.jpg"},{"store_id":"91","seller_id":"293","name":"Rodds Kitchens and Joinery","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_293_logorodds_kitchens_logo.jpg"},{"store_id":"95","seller_id":"297","name":"SMART FLATPACK & ASSEMBLED","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/skin\/frontend\/default\/market_place\/marketplace\/images\/image.jpg"},{"store_id":"96","seller_id":"303","name":"Jindabyne Joinery","logo":"http:\/\/dev.joinerytrade.com\/media\/marketplace\/resized\/MP_303_logoJindy3.jpg"}]}
```

Comment: what is the logic You are using to print the seller_id

Comment: no.use seller_id to retrieve data like, product name, price,type..@prabs

Comment: i update my question.

Comment: Can't understand your question completeley? Please add more details.

Comment: check it.i update my question...